# Use named router-outlet for a lazy loaded or child module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-components

I'm trying to load pages with a config bar at the top. Each page will have a different config setup which are children of the page.

My app.component.html has

```
<router-outlet name="config"></router-outlet>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My app-routering.module.ts has

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'LastTradedPrices', component: LastTradedPricesComponent }

  { path: 'Slippage/:group', loadChildren: './slippage/slippage.module#SlippageModule' }
];
```

Here's the routes for the SlippageComponent

```
const slippageRoutes: Routes = [
    { 
        path: '', 
        component: SlippageComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ConfigComponent,
                outlet: 'config'
            }
        ] 
    }
];
```

Basically I want the default outlet to show page data from the SlippageComponent and to load the ConfigComponenet into the named 'config' outlet above it.

Answer (score 0):

Child Component ***ConfigComponent*** looks for **router-outlet** in parent component ***SlippageComponent***

For the given ***app.component.html***, Change Slippage routes as below.

```
const slippageRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ConfigComponent,
    outlet: 'config'
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: SlippageComponent,
  }
];
```